# Eclipse Collection usages on production code

Tags: java, eclipse-collections

https://www.eclipse.org/collections/ seems to be getting popular now a days. Just wonder, if anybody has used this library in their production code and how is the overall experience.

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse Collections was previously a GS-Collections (Goldman-Sachs), so yes, it is used in production. You can check out their github, before the migration to Eclipse foundation - https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections.

I heard good opinions about Eclipse Collections, that it's performing really well memory-wise and the API is well-designed and good to use from client's perspective. Tried it myself, definitely agree about the API, not sure about memory aspects since my project is not so memory-critical and was doing fine with Java standard collections. It's still fine after migration to Eclipse Collections, so from my experience they are at least as good as Java collections. The huge advantage over Java collections are the Primitive Collections (name says it all I guess), so before Java 10 this is definitely a major thing in favor of Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) is used in other open source projects including [Neo4J](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j), [MapDB](https://github.com/jankotek/mapdb), [Reladomo](https://github.com/goldmansachs/reladomo) and [FINOS Legend](https://github.com/finos/legend-pure). Any applications that use these projects in production are using Eclipse Collections in production.

Eclipse Collections is an active participant in the [OpenJDK Quality Outreach program](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/quality/Quality+Outreach), and [shares feedback on issues it discovers](https://stuartmarks.wordpress.com/2020/09/22/incompatibilities-with-jdk-15-charsequence-isempty/) with the Core JDK team at Oracle on EA versions of Java it is tested against.

**Note**: I am the creator of Eclipse Collections, so am biased. I have used Eclipse Collections and its predecessors ([GS Collections and Caramel](https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/01/GS-Collections-Eclipse-Foundn/)) in many production applications for the past 18 years. It has been developed in open source on GitHub for over a decade now. I am still an active Project Lead and Committer on the project, and the project is open to the community for contributions at the [Eclipse Foundation](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.collections). After 18 years, my experience continues to be overwhelmingly positive. I continue to work on and use Eclipse Collections in production applications at my current employer. I also blog about [Eclipse Collections on Medium](https://medium.com/tag/eclipse-collections), along with a few other contributors.